# Javascript regex select different contents in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to build a regex to retrieve/select elements in an encoded string depending some keyboard signs order:

```
 str = "(abc-1é,d[efg_2ç;i|jkl+3ö.(mno?4à,p[qr(st!5',uv#6^;|xyz%7_." // look strange :)
```

I need to retrieve all parts included

1) in **( ,** -> "abc-1é" + "mno?4à" + "st!5'"

2) in **[ ;** -> "efg_2ç" + "qr(st!5,uv#6^"

3) in **| .** -> "jkl+3ö" + "xyz%7_"

I've tried a lot of possibilities on https://regex101.com/ and I'm able to produce some right results:

```
/\(([^()]*),/g -> catch "(abc-1é," "(mno?4à," and "(st!5'," -> OK

/\|[\w()]{0,}(...)./g -> catch "|jkl+3ö."  and  "|xyz%7_." -> OK
```

Don't ask me why but it works, except:

```
/\[([^()]*);/g  or /\[[\w()]{0,}(...);/g  -> catch "[efg_2ç;" but ignore "[qr(st!5',uv#6^;"
```

My question is: is it possible to create an **unique regex** able to capture the 3 signs-conditions? something like:

```
 / init: \[|\(|\| -> inside: [all founded signs, any length] -> end: ,|.|; /g
```

and (if possible) with some explanations... Thx in advance

Comment: OK,  `[qr(st!5',uv#6^;`  works well if signs ! ' and , are declared in the regex `[[\w(),!']{0,}(...);`

Comment: This mighty single regex, capable of matching everything at once, does not exist due to interferences of rivaling patterns. Use 3 patterns each limited to exactly its use case. Use it with `matchAll` results that get destructured/flattened into a single array and then reduced or mapped. This also helps readability and refactoring/maintenance.

Comment: OK. What I'm tying to do is to encode for storage a kind on contract built on if->then->else imbricated conditions to be reused later. For example 
`(a:b,A[c>d;|B[c>d;.` once decoded says `if (number of votes > 10) { Approve(name,decision) } else { Reject(name,decision) }`

Each actor will be able to safely store its own conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mighty single regex, capable of matching everything at once, does not exist due to interferences of rivaling patterns. One might use 3 patterns instead, each limited to exactly its special use case.

A possible approach then makes use of `matchAll` for each pattern, does convert/destructure and collect each result-array into a single array and finally maps all the captures. Such an approach also is more readable and better for refactoring/maintenance ...

```js
// (/(?:\((?<pc>[^,]*),)|(?:\[(?<bs>[^;]*);)|(?:\|(?<pp>[^\.]*)\.)/gm);

const regxParenthesesComma = (/\(([^,]*),/gm);
const regxBracketSemicolon = (/\[([^;]*);/gm);
const regxPipePeriod = (/\|([^\.]*)\./gm);

function extractCharacterSequences(str) {
  return [

    ...str.matchAll(regxParenthesesComma),
    ...str.matchAll(regxBracketSemicolon),
    ...str.matchAll(regxPipePeriod)

  ].map(result => result[1]);
}

const test = "(abc-1é,d[efg_2ç;i|jkl+3ö.(mno?4à,p[qr(st!5',uv#6^;|xyz%7_.";

console.log(
  'extractCharacterSequences(test) => ',
  extractCharacterSequences(test)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wooooow @Peter :-) greaaaaaaaaaat

Comment: @Wolden ... what does "wooow" mean? Did the approach solve the problem? Is there anything that still needs to be improved?

Comment: perfectly solved, thanks :-)  [except `str.matchAll` is not accepted by all browsers but it works as expected when working :-) ]

Comment: @Wolden ... is it the accepted approach then, or does the OP need  a solution that works in a yet to be specified environment?

Comment: I've checked all options (accepted)(solved)(approved) :-)

Comment: Thanks, and I was serious about another approach except for `matchAll`.